# What's the best method for downloading a PDF from a sapUI5 App?

Tags: pdf, svg, sapui5

I need a 'Download PDF' feature for my SAPUI5 app which contains Viz charts (SVG's) as well as other more standard HTML elements.

I've already looked into jsPDF, html2canvas etc.

What is the recommended method?

It needs to work both as a Web app and also as a packaged Cordova app.

Comment: Do you already have the PDF file? or does it need to be generated?

Answer (score 0):

This has been somewhat answered here: [Save Web page directly to PDF using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28522749/save-web-page-directly-to-pdf-using-js)

This method should work both in web app and as a Cordova app.

As mentioned there the best choice would still be to popup the "print to PDF" window (just as pressing ctrl+p in most browsers) and letting the user save it.

Cheers.