# Save a pre element as PDF with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I made a [syntax highlighter](http://output.jsbin.com/cokico/) and I want an option to save as a PDF. I've looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript), but downloading it doesn’t preserve the CSS styling, which ruins the point of downloading the highlighted file. Is there a way I can save my `pre` element as a PDF while maintaining the CSS?

HTML:

```
<pre id='output'> (highlighted portion) </pre>
<button id='save'>Save as PDF</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
  //this is what I need help with
});
```

As you may have noticed, I'm using jQuery, if that matters.

Comment: I only want to print the `pre`, not the entire page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening new `window` , appending `pre` `html` , `style` , if any for `pre` element, to new `window` `document.body` , calling `.focus()` , `.print()` on new `window` ; select system print dialog, select "Print to file"

```
$("#save").click(function() {
  var text = $("#output")[0].outerHTML;
  // `styles`: `style` element; 
  // or `String` "<style>.light{color:#0af;}</style>" ;
  // alternatively , add `style` attribute to `pre` element directly,
  // e.g., `<pre style="color:#0af;">`
  var styles = $("style")[0].outerHTML;
  var popup = window.open("", "popup");
  // append `text`:`pre` element `styles`:`style` element
  // at `popup` `document.body`
  popup.document.body.innerHTML = text + styles;
  popup.focus();
  popup.print();
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tn04Ldka/2/

Comment: Thanks, but CSS is not preserved. Is there an addition to this answer that would allow the use of CSS, or would this require a different approach? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyoce/tn04Ldka/)

Comment: @Cyoce See updated post. Could add `style` element from initial document to `popup` document; add `style` attribute to `pre` element; or, create `String` `"<style>.light{color:#0af;}</style>"` that should be rendered as `html` at `popup` , and be applied to `pre.light` element.