# Convert Html Form to Pdf along with radio buttons and checkbox in php

Tags: java, php, jquery, html, pdf

I have a form with 100's of fields along with radio and check-box. What will be the best way to create PDF from it. Here is the link to my form 'http://182.71.22.42/ccs/'. I have used 'JSPDF' library but it just prints text only in PDF not any input field. I have also tried 'TCPDF' but I don't know how  to show check-box and radio buttons and also I have to do css for 'TCPDF' also. Because TCPDF does not pick any HTML form css..

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at mPDF. It's pretty good and should do what you want. Also, fyi that link you posted is behind a login box.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135765/save-a-pre-element-as-pdf-with-css

Answer (score 0):

I like [pdftk (PDF Tool Kit)](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). It's fairly easy to use. There is a GUI, but there's also a command line tool -- which is obviously what you'll want to use. You'll install the pdftk program on your server, and run it from your PHP script.

## PDFTK General Tutorial

1. Firstly, a blank PDF file should reside on your server. The empty fields should be labeled such that you can reference them.
2. When a user inputs information via your form, the data should be sanitized and inserted into an [FDF (Forms Document File)](http://www.verypdf.com/pdfform/fdf.htm).
3. Once you have your FDF completed, in your PHP script, run:

`exec('pdftk blank.pdf fill_form new.fdf output finished.pdf');`

Where `blank.pdf` is the empty PDF, `new.fdf` is the FDF you just created, and `finished.pdf` is the name of the file you want pdftk to create for you.

Comment: Thanks for your replies .I found solution in TCPDF to show checkboxes. Just use different images, one for checked checkbox and other for unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies .I found solution in TCPDF to show checkboxes. Just use different images, one for checked checkbox and other for unchecked