# Generating PDF for html content including its styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

I am using jspdf.min.js to genarate pdf for my content
I am able genarate pdf using jspdf.min.js but i am unable to apply the styles of the elements into my pdf file

See the below for example

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
 '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
  return true;
 }
};
$('#cmd').click(function () {
 doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
  'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
 });
 doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <h3 style="color: red">Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>
  <p>a pararaph</p>
</div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

Here it is not working check the following jsFiddle for the working example

Link: [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manikanta_viswa/a4bxaqoh/)

Comment: Don't you have to call "html2pdf" function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135765/save-a-pre-element-as-pdf-with-css