# How to convert HTML(CSS) To PDF Using JavaScript bowser independent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want convert my web page with css to PDF on button click event in java script or jquery.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135765/save-a-pre-element-as-pdf-with-css

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a package out there that does this for you

https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf

*"css2pdf is a simple to use Javascript for CSS to PDF rendering that can easily be plugged-in to your website."*

Example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('Usage',{render:'download'});">
    <img src="button-print.png">
</a>
```