# JavaScript Print Function not carrying the stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

So let's start with the code:

```
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=600,width=800');


        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><base href="/" /><title>' + document.title + '</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<style type="text/css" media="print" />table { width: 100%; }</style>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write('<h1> Returns for Today </h1>');
        mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(printableArea).innerHTML);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
```

The code is pretty working with this output

[image]

And then when I change the css to an external stylesheet like this:

**From**  `mywindow.document.write('<style type="text/css" media="print" />table { width: 100%; }</style>');`

**To** `mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/printstyles.css" type="text/css" />');`

I get a blank print page:

[image]

But if I comment the line

```
//mywindow.print();
//mywindow.close();
```

I get this:

[image]

Meaning, the external stylesheet is working.

The external stylesheet only includes

```
table { width: 100%; }
```

Any idea why it is not working? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [Save a pre element as PDF with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30135765/)

Comment: Add media="print" to the reference of your external stylesheet.

Comment: @jeff, did that and it worked though no styles haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same issue in Chrome. The problem I found was that the print preview doesn't completely render, but the page still prints without issues.

What I ended up doing was something like this:

```
var mywindow = window.open("", ...);
mywindow.document.write("...");
mywindow.document.close();
setTimeout(function() {
  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();
}, 10);
```

Comment: The problem is that loading a stylesheet is asynchronous, and you were calling `print()` before it finished.

Comment: The problem still occurs if you add a `<style>`. I think it's just the print preview render stopping when you `close()` right away.