# HTML string to pdf conversion with style angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf, export

Can you please help me with a way to download pdf from an HTML string which also has style in it. 
I am showing the HTML string with 'window.document.write' and opening it in a new tab. so it has no URL or there is no option like save as pdf.
I have tried using jsPDF.

```
        var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4');
        var options = {
            pagesplit: true
        };

        doc.addHTML(this.html, 0, 0, options, function () {
            doc.save('test.pdf');
        });
```

but it gives me error like

[image]

here my HTML string is quite big, with tables, rows columns, and also style in it. 
I have also looked for some other libraries. But found nothing that does the job. 
It would be really appreciable if you can show me a right way.

Comment: See [Save a pre element as PDF with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135765/save-a-pre-element-as-pdf-with-css/30137788#30137788)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It worked for printing. But I want to download the report as pdf. Can you suggest me please. @guest271314

Comment: Click `"Save as PDF"` at print dialog.