# App Script HTML to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, google-apps-script

I'm using Google App Script and I want to convert the contents of a div in a pdf file. I'm trying:

```
function genPdf(html)
{
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, "text/html", "text.html");
  var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");
  DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName("text.pdf"); 
}
```

The 'html' parameter of the function is passed with a

```
$('#container').html()
```

The problem is when I get the html of the div with the Jquery's html() function, it returns me the html without the CSS styles and/or images.

I need to generate a PDF with exactly the same content of the div.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question isn't very clear, so you'll probably find it gets closed as a duplicate to [Generate pdf from HTML in div using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191893), [Download a div in a HTML page as pdf using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135) or something similar. It seems that you want to save a PDF to your Google Drive, with the complete contents of a div from a page served by Google Apps Script's HtmlService.

Comment: try inline css inside the html

Comment: is it possible to convert pdf to html in the same way

Answer (score 0):

the inline css will work when html is retrieved from jquery but the html view cannot be same in the pdf also. I had problems with alignment of the tables in pdf format.