# Export html to pdf using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf, export-to-pdf

Hi I want to Export html to pdf, I have use jsPDF all are working pdf also exporting but i want to get same html in pdf, html styles are not working what can I do for that can anyone help me please? Is their are any way to use html styles in jsPDF?? This is my html code. I got a script function from this link http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/1/

```
   <div class="panel col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-11" style="" id="quotation">


    <header><img src="~/images/doc/header_footer/TOUR_Header.png" width="600" /></header>
    <table width="600" border="0" style="font-size:12px;border:none;" ng-repeat="endetails in enquiryQuote" id="enq_details">

        <tr>
            <td><b>Enquiry Date</b></td>
            <td>{{endetails.system_date_time | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td><b>Enquiry ref.</b></td>
            <td>{{endetails.reference_no}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Dep. date</b></td>
            <td>{{endetails.departing_date | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td><b>Depart. from</b></td>
            <td>{{endetails.departing_from}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Ret. date</b></td>
            <td>{{endetails.returning_date | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td><b>Travel. to</b></td>
            <td>{{endetails.travelling_to}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b>Customer</b></td>
            <td>{{endetails.name}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table width="300" border="0" style="font-size:12px;border:none;" ng-repeat="total in invoice_total">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Total Price</b></td>
            <td>{{total.total_amount}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table width="600" border="0" style="" ng-repeat="product in invheader[0].invoice_hotel">
        <tr>
            <td><font color="red;">Hotel Details</font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Hotel name</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product.hotel_name}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>No of rooms</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product.no_of_rooms}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Location</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product.city_code}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;">Room view</td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product.product_hotel_room_views.roomview_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Checkin</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product.check_in| date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;">Room type</td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product.product_hotel_room_types.room_type_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Checkout</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product.check_out| date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;">Board basis</td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product.product_hotel_board_basis.bb_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>No of nights</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:150px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:300px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <b>Passengers - Rooms</b>
                <div ng-repeat="item in product.product_hotel_room"><b>Adult :</b> {{item.adults}} and <b>Child :</b> {{item.child}}</div>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Budget</b></td>
            <td>{{product.payable}}</td>
            <td><b>Rate</b></td>
            <td>{{product.rate}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <table width="600" border="0" style="" ng-repeat="product_flight in invheader[0].invoice_flight">
        <tr>
            <td><font color="red;">Flight Details</font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Depatur City</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_flight.departure_city}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Arrival City</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_flight.arrival_city}}</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Depature date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_flight.depature_date | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Arrival Date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_flight.arrival_date | date:fullDate}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <b>Passengers</b>
                <br />
                <div ng-repeat="item_flight_pass in product_flight.invoice_flight_passengers"><b>Name :</b>{{item_flight_pass.title}}.{{item_flight_pass.first_name}}&nbsp;{{item_flight_pass.last_name}} </div>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Budget</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; {{product_flight.budget}}</td>
            <td><b>Total</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; {{product_flight.total_sell_amt}} </td>
            <td><b>Commision</b>&nbsp;&nbsp; {{product_flight.commission_on}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" border="0" style="" ng-repeat="product_car in invheader[0].invoice_car">
        <tr>
            <td><font color="red;">Car Details</font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 178px;"><b>Pick Up</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_car.pickup}}</td>
            <td style="width: 178px;"><b>Drop off</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_car.dropoff}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 178px;"><b>Pick Up date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_car.datein | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width: 178px;"><b>Drop off Date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_car.dateout | date:fullDate}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width: 178px;"><b>Pick Up Time</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_car.timein | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width: 180px;"><b>Drop off Time</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_car.timeout | date:fullDate}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Car Type</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_car.type}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Budget</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_car.payable}}</td>
            <td><b>Total</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_car.buyamount}}</td>
            <td><b>Commision</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_car.commissionon}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" border="0" style="" ng-repeat="product_tour in invheader[0].invoice_tour">

        <tr>
            <td><font color="red;">Tour Details</font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tour Details</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Pick Up</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_tour.pick_up}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Drop off</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_tour.drop_off}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Pick Up date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_tour.departure_date | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Drop off Date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_tour.dateout | date:fullDate}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Pick Up Time</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_tour.timein | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Drop off Time</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_tour.timeout | date:fullDate}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Budget</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_tour.payable}}</td>
            <td><b>Total</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_tour.buyamount}}</td>
            <td><b>Commision</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_tour.commissionon}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" border="0" style="" ng-repeat="product_rail in invheader[0].invoice_rail">
        <tr>
            <td><font color="red;">Rail Details</font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Departure</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_rail.departurecity}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Arrival</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_rail.arrivalcity}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Type</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_rail.type}}</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Budget</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_rail.budget}}</td>
            <td><b>Total</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_rail.amount}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Quote Price</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_rail.quote_price}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table width="600" border="0" style="" ng-repeat="product_transfer in invheader[0].invoice_transfers">
        <tr>
            <td><font color="red;">Transfers Details</font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>From City</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_transfer.from_city}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>To City</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_transfer.to_city}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Vehicle Type</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_transfer.vehicle_type}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Budget</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_transfer.budget}}</td>
            <td><b>Buy Amount</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_transfer.amount}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Payable</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_transfer.payable}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" border="0" style="" ng-repeat="product_cruise in invheader[0].invoice_cruise">
        <tr>
            <td><font color="red;">Cruise Details</font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Departure City</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_cruise.departure_city}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Arrival City</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_cruise.arrival_city}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Type</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_cruise.vehicle_type}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Departure date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_cruise.departure_date | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Arrival Date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_cruise.arrival_date | date:fullDate}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Depature Time</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_cruise.departure_time | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Arivalo Time</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_cruise.arrival_time | date:fullDate}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Budget</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_cruise.budget}}</td>
            <td><b>Amount</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_cruise.amount}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Commistion Amount</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_cruise.commission_amount}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table width="600" border="0" style="" ng-repeat="product_insurance in invheader[0].invoice_insurance">
        <tr>
            <td><font color="red;">Insurance Details</font></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Departure City</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_insurance.departure_city}}</td>
            <td style="width:150px;"><b>Arrival City</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_insurance.arrival_city}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Type</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_insurance.vehicle_type}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Departure date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_insurance.departure_date | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Arrival Date</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_insurance.arrival_date | date:fullDate}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Depature Time</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_insurance.departure_time | date:fullDate}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Arivalo Time</b></td>
            <td style="width:300px;">{{product_insurance.arrival_time | date:fullDate}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Budget</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_insurance.budget}}</td>
            <td><b>Amount</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_insurance.amount}}</td>
            <td style="width:165px;"><b>Commistion Amount</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product_insurance.commission_amount}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <footer><img src="~/images/doc/header_footer/TOUR_Footer.png" width="600" /></footer>

</div>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="rightpan" id='printablediv'>
<p>Print Content</p>
<input type='button' id="cmd" value="Download" class="button1 sbtbutton" />
<div>
<div style="display: none;" id="editor"></div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var element = $("#printablediv"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable

$("#cmd").on('click', function () {

    html2canvas(element, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            $("#editor").append(canvas);
            getCanvas = canvas;

            var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
            doc = new jsPDF({
                unit: 'px',
                format: 'a4'
            });
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
            doc.save('Vistordetails.pdf');
            form.width(cache_width);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice one that i found

Answer (score 1):

Late Answer!!

1. Use [Html2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) plugin to convert a div to canvas
2. next add the canvas image to [JsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) doc