# export html to PDF in JSPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I have data wrapped in DIV
And I'm interested in exporting them to PDF
Using JSPDF

```
const openPdf=()=>{
  var doc = new JSPDF()
 html2pdf(document.getElementById("jsPdf"), pdf, function(pdf){
pdf.save('file.pdf');

}
<div id ="jsPdf">
  {
    res.map((file)=>{
  file.comment,
  file.title
  })
}
</div>
```

And I also want a page to go after each loop loop
how do I do it?

Comment: Duplicate! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748878/export-html-to-pdf-using-jspdf please use the search function to find similar questions before posting.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach :=)

here is peace of script from my project

```
  public SavePDF(): void {
    let pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a3');
    pdf.html(<HTMLElement>document.getElementById('excel-table'), {
      callback: function (pdf) {
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

[mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/) may be a good option to solve your problem

Comment: but i want with jspdf

Comment: @programmer: jspdf is very well documented with lots of examples. You have to show more code with a precise question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask