# I am getting " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined " error when I use jspdf to download html div content as pdf

Tags: html, pdf, download, jspdf

I am creating a student ID card and then I am creating a button below it to give an option to the user to download the ID card as PDF.

My ID card div is as follows:

```
      <!doctype html>             
      <html>
      <head>
      <title>Admin Registration</title>
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/show_message.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
      <script type=\"text/javascript\">
       $(document).ready(function() {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
         '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
         return true;
       }
      };

        $('#cmd').click(function () {

          doc.fromHTML($('receipt-outer').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,\n" +
          'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
          });
          doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
          });
        });
    </script>
    </head>

     <body>

   <div class='receipt-outer'>
   <div class="receipt-inner">           
   <div class='idcard_heading'><p>Student ID Card</p></div>      
   <div class='clear'></div>
   <div class='receipt_details'>
   <div class='idcard_heading1'>
   <div class='id_pic'>

   <div class='id_pic_inner'>
   <img src='images/pic"+fno+".jpg'  height='120px' width='140px'><br>
   <img src='images/sign"+fno+".jpg'  height='50px' width='140px'>
   </div>

   <table id='id_table'>"+
   <tr><th>Name : </th><td>"+s_fname+" "+s_mname+" "+s_sname+"</td></tr>                 
   <tr><th>Course Name : </th><td>"+cname+"</td></tr>
   <tr><th>Course code : </th><td>"+ccode+"</td></tr>                        
   <tr><th>Commence of course : </th><td>"+st_from+"</td></tr>
   <tr><th>End of course : </th><td>"+till+"</td></tr>
   <tr><th>Timing : </th><td>"+ctiming+"</td></tr>                       
   </table>
   </div><br>
   <div style='height:30px; margin-top:20px; margin-right:20px;'>
     <span style='float:right;'>Issuing Authority</span></div>

     <div id='editor'></div>

   </div>

   </div>
   </div><br><br>
   <button id='cmd'>Download </button>

   </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

I want to download the part of the div starting from the div class="receipt-outer" to the end in pdf format,  just excluding the download button.

So I imported jspdf.min.js file and created a script which listens to the click event and then downloads the div as pdf. But I am getting the above mentioned error in the console whenever I hit the download button.

Please tell me where have I gone wrong. Why is it not downloading my file as pdf

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

dompdf might be what you are looking for:

Available here:

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf