# Web Page content Download as pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm designing a web page and want to download the content of the page by download button as **PDF** but i don't know how to implement this.

Comment: I think your question has already an answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try using https://plugins.jquery.com/printThis/

Also Can use JsPdf Both are good.