# How to download primeng datatable in pdf format

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, primeng-datatable

**html**

```
 <p-dataTable [hidden]="loading" [rowStyleClass]="customRowClass" [value]="timePeriods" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="400px">
        <p-column field="StartDate" header="Begindatum" sortable="false">
            <template let-col let-timePeriod="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                <span [class.missingPeriod]="!timePeriod.IsNext">{{timePeriod.StartDate | date: 'dd-MM yyyy'}}</span>
            </template>
        </p-column>
        <p-column field="EndDate" header="Einddatum" sortable="false">
            <template let-col let-timePeriod="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
                <span>{{timePeriod.EndDate | date: 'dd-MM yyyy'}}</span>
            </template>
        </p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

### PrimeNG

Right now there is not yet support for exporting a PrimeNG datatable to PDF.

This feature is on the roadmap though, you can see it [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Roadmap#datatable).

### jsPDF

What you could do is downloading a div as a PDF using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript) on Stackoverflow for an implementation.

Comment: jsPDF takes the screenshot and download the html in PDF format.

Comment: @Vignesh Yes, you will only have the data that is shown to the user.

Comment: If i want to download a primeng  datatable in csv format with expression values and pipes it's not loading in download data.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly. In this example I managed to export all rows to a csv file (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2u8ahh).

Comment: For example i have formatted the EndDate in expression  "<span>{{timePeriod.EndDate | date: 'dd-MM yyyy'}}</span>" and assigned to table.  I want to  download data in csv format with formatted Date.