# Problems using window.print() method

Tags: javascript, html, pdf-generation

I'm using `window.print()` method in JavaScript but I have the problems listed below:

- Zooming in or out ruins page formation
- Resizing the page does the same
- I can't define end of each page

Do you know how to solve these problems?
I've tried disabling window resize but it didn't work.

Is it possible to use `window.print()` but the print dialogue wouldn't be shown and the pdf would be started to be downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a [print stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing)

Comment: I think you might need a library, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript#answer-17294247

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful.