# Save a div (Which is on a different server) as pdf with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html2pdf

I am trying to save a **div** as **pdf** file from a website which is not mine (A random website).

I have used **[html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.0)** in my website to convert a div to pdf. But could it be used to save a div on a different website? 
Or any other javascript/jQuery plugin that can be used for this task?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I don't know this is going to help you but please check the second answer for this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript

Comment: @RichárdBaldauf thanks bro, but the given solution doesnt work for me. you have to include that code in your website to execute it. The div I want to convert is not on my website but on a different one.

Comment: You can't access the content of arbitrary websites on the browser.